# Fitting Gaussian distribution with indirect observations

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, curve-fitting, probit, quantile-regression

I want to estimate the mean and variance of a gaussian random variable $X$.

The realizations of $X$, i.e. $x$, are not observable. Instead, $a$ and $b$ are observed, which are related to $X$ via

$P(x \geq a+n)= b$,

where $n$ is an unknown small noise term.

How can I fit $X$ to a gaussian distribution by using a collection of $a$ and $b$ realizations?

Comment: What do you know about $n$?

Comment: @Tim not much. But we can assume it is white gaussian with small variance compared to the value of b.

Comment: Presumably you must have the variance of your noise term decrease as $b$ gets near 0 or 1 or you'll have probabilities that are outside (0,1)

Comment: @Glen_b I agree. This is a model I have made my self. The noise term is to  account for the fact that $a$ and $b$ are sample means of some quantities I can not measure, and not the analytical probabilities. Most of the sample I  have are for $b$ values between $0.3$ and $0.8$.

Comment: @Glen_b I have edited the equation. Now extreme negative values of n do not give negative probabilities.

Comment: Now you have something that starts to look something like a [probit model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model). (Another common choice would be a logit model, which would correspond to unobserved logistic noise.)

Comment: This sounds like [quantile regression.](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiC-rOo17LQAhVBiRoKHYnPBmQQFggfMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FQuantile_regression&usg=AFQjCNH6gp5t4dupyoKslcosXfIS11rKUA&sig2=lm70Ck1XHpGs9CuMDrtrWg)

Comment: @Xi'an I think that quantile regressions are quite close to what I'm looking for. However, as far as I know, quantile regression will give information about $P(x \geq a +n) =b$ and not $x$ it self. I'm right?